# Python Wiki Style Doc Generator

Tags: python, documentation, wiki, pydoc

Looking for something like PyDoc that can generate a set of Wiki style pages vs the current HTML ones that export out of PyDoc. I would like to be able to export these in Google Code's Wiki as an extension to the current docs up there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at pydoc.TextDoc. If this contains too little markup, you can inherit from it and make it generate markup according to your wiki's syntax.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking about doing. Just was hoping someone had already done the work or had the idea already.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/)?

Comment: I have, but I don't think it exports to Wiki format. Yet alone it does more then what I need at this point as all I'm looking for is a basic package, module, class break down documentation. It might be something to look into expanding it like suggest above with PyDoc to do a Wiki style generation.

Comment: [pdoc](https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc) exports to markdown which can then be transcoded into wiki format with [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/).